# Using separate data sets for the same fixture

Tags: cakephp, fixtures

I have a shell that sends out emails updating a person on their account status.  In order to compile the list of people who need to receive this email today, I have a method that executes the appropriate `find('all')` query and returns the list of recipients.  I want to unit test this method to make sure this list is being generated correctly.

However, now I have two unit tests depending on my Person fixture - my Person model's test, and this shell test.  The extra clutter from the Person model test makes it awkward to prepare a data set focused on my shell test.  The tests are complected - if I change the data set for one, I might break the other.

Can I easily define separate data sets for the same fixture depending on the context?  Can I create separate fixtures for separate tests?  How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create as many fixtures as you like.  You can choose which fixtures are loaded by your TestCase using the following declaration `public $fixtures = array('app.Fixture1', 'app.Ficture2', etc...);`.

You can import table information from your default database connection so its easy to create multiple fixtures for the same model (i.e. PersonFixture1, PersonFixture2). 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#importing-table-information-and-records

Also, you can override the init method of your fixtures to dynamically load record data (i.e. alter timestamps).
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#dynamic-data-and-fixtures

Hope this helps.

Comment: Further, if you are using statically defined table structures instead of import (like me), you can finish this up by setting the [`$name` property](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/TestSuite/Fixture/CakeTestFixture.php#L26) to the appropriate value (in my case, "Person").